# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueParamProvider

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish

I am trying to run my maven application but getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/internal/ValueParamProvider
    at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.installer.feature.jersey.provider.JerseyProviderInstaller.<clinit>(JerseyProviderInstaller.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.GuiceyInitializer.prepareInstallers(GuiceyInitializer.java:217)
    at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.GuiceyInitializer.resolveInstallers(GuiceyInitializer.java:119)
    at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.initialize(GuiceBundle.java:123)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.addBundle(Bootstrap.java:150)
    at com.test.aae.aggregator.facade.App.initialize(App.java:164)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:88)
    at com.test.aae.aggregator.facade.App.main(App.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueParamProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

I am using the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey-guava.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My app is running with java 17

Comment: ValueParamProvider was added in Jersey 2.26. If you're using Dropwizard, 1) you don't need any _base_ Jersey dependencies 2) If you do use any Jersey dependencies, make sure they are the same version Dropwizard is using.

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha I am using dropwizard2 (v2.0.23)

Comment: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/2b53cc355d22691d81f38069cfb25180445e1ae6/dropwizard-dependencies/pom.xml#L49

Comment: You should also check what version of Jersey that third-party dropwizard-guicy is using. That seems to be the culprit by looking at the stack trace